# Intel XDK can't install debug module

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, phonegap-plugins, intel-xdk

Recently I was building a Cordova app in Intel XDK. Everything worked fine, but I've decided to remove one of the plugins (for caching images locally) and I did it (it appears on the list that it is removed from project but not updated yet in debug module).

After that I can't generate debug module - I receive an error:

```
Could not generate debug module: Debug module Erorr: Request expired. Try again.
```

Of course I've tried this couple times, restarted Intel XDK, reinstalled it with removing whole `~/Library/Application\ Support/XDK/` folder and reinstalling `App preview` application on mobile phone but without success.

When I remove all local debug modules Intel XDK suggest to install generic debug module but it doesn't work either.

I'm on OSX 10.10.5, phone is LG G2 Mini, connected via USB cable.

Comment: same here. tried 2 different workstations. Made a new project, but still the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The server is back up. Give it another shot now.