# IntelXDK keeps showing building but nothing happens

Tags: android, intel-xdk, construct-2, crosswalk

I am using XDK for a while but suddenly whenever i build codova apk then it successfully uploads file to server but when i hit build app then it keeps showing building and then after few minutes it goes back to build page and did't build the app. And no error is shown.

Can anyone please give me a solution[image]

Comment: Be patient, it can sometimes take a long time.

Comment: no its shows building and then goes back to build screen without showing any error or something and didn't build the app

Answer (score 1):

Your issue might be related to this [Intel XDK can't install debug module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34741444/intel-xdk-cant-install-debug-module)
Debugging is also an issue, I suspect the compilation servers are down

Comment: Yeah I think that was the issue because it working fine now automatically